# Install Ubuntu with downloaded softwares and updates from the Live USB

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I want to install Ubuntu for my dad on an old computer but he lives in a farm without any Internet.

Is it possible to create a bootable usb, Install some software I think he might find useful on the USB, do a update of the system and then do a full install on my dad's computer when I'm on the farm again without having to worry about the latest updates?

Hope I'm making sense here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done straightforward from the Live USB. Because, what you will install on the Live USB, won't get installed on the new system of the hard drive. But You can probably go with these instruction:

- Make a bootable Live USB with a bigger persistent file.
- Boot from the USB.
- Install necessary updates and useful softwares. Don't forget `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package
- Grab the downloaded .deb files from `/var/cache/apt/archives/` directory.
- Put these .deb files somewhere else for later use.
- When you're in the farm, Install the Ubuntu system on your dad's PC from the Live USB.
- Reboot into newly installed system.
- Then transfer back all those `.deb` files you copied to a directory of your choice.
- Now open a Terminal (`Ctrl-Alt-T`) and cd to the directory of copied deb files
- Use `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` command to install all these deb files (*There will be no dependency problem because these are the only packages this new system knows*)

**Note:** Make sure not to accept Microsoft EULA for `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package, because if you accept those `apt` will try to download the files from Internet and eventually will fail.

Comment: This worked for me. My dad is enjoying his 'new' ubuntu pc.

Comment: Great to hear this. :)